# Relative Uri works for BitmapImage, but not for MediaPlayer?

Tags: wpf, uri, relative-path, absolute-path

This will be simple for you guys:

```
var uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/LiftExperiment;component/pics/outside/elevator.jpg");
imageBitmap = new BitmapImage();
imageBitmap.BeginInit();
imageBitmap.UriSource = uri;
imageBitmap.EndInit();
image.Source = imageBitmap;
```

=> Works perfectly on a .jpg with 
Build Action: Content
Copy to Output Directory: Copy always

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
var uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/LiftExperiment;component/sounds/DialingTone.wav");
mp.Open(uri);
mp.Play();
```

=> Does not work on a .wav with the same build action and copy to output. I see the file in my /debug/ folder..

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
var uri = new Uri(@"E:\projects\LiftExp\_solution\LiftExperiment\bin\Debug\sounds\DialingTone.wav");
mp.Open(uri);
mp.Play();
```

=> Works perfectly..

So, how do I get the sound to work with a relative path? Why is it not working this way?
Let me know if you want more code or screenshots.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pack://application URI syntax is for "embed" files, make sure the the media file is set to that, or use the pack://siteoforigin for "loose" files (copied to bin directory).

[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Then why does it work for the first example with the BitmapImage?

Comment: heh, it works with this:
var uri = new Uri("pack://siteoforigin:,,,/sounds/DialingTone.wav");

I had to remove "/LiftExperiment;component"