# How to play WAV audio file in Resources with MediaPlayer in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

I could play wav audio file in Resources with the code below.

The files were added to Resources by:

Practice_AccessResource > File > Properties > Resources > Audio > Add > ExistingFiles

```
//only can play audio file with SoundPlayer class.
System.IO.Stream strForMusic = Practice_AccessResourceFile.Properties.Resources.TaDa;
System.Media.SoundPlayer sountPlayer = new 
System.Media.SoundPlayer(strForMusic);
sountPlayer.Play();
```

FYI, the project name is the "**Practice_AccessResourceFile**", and name of wav audio file is **TaDa.wav** ,   sorry that I could not change the name for u.

Is there any way to play audio file with MediaPlayer in WPF?

```
System.IO.Stream stream = Properties.Resources.TaDa;
MediaPlayer musicPlayer = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
//musicPlayer.Open(new System.Uri(stream));  //This is not working
//musicPlayer.Play();
```

I have to play two music simultaneously, and it's not possible with SoundPlayer.

Can anyone help me play audio file with MediaPlayer class in WPF?

Comment: You have to use the wonky pack syntax, as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2625608/17034).

Comment: ohh.. I think I will just create the audio file in temp folder and play it locally... Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe MediaPlayer cannot play from Resources, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44369356/c-sharp-mediaplayer-doesnt-play-mp3-file-from-resources) for example.

If you can write the files to a temporary folder on disk then it should be be possible, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240002/play-two-sounds-simultaneusly):

```
var p1 = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
p1.Open(new System.Uri(@"C:\windows\media\tada.wav"));
p1.Play();

// this sleep is here just so you can distinguish the two sounds playing simultaneously
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

var p2 = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
p2.Open(new System.Uri(@"C:\windows\media\tada.wav"));
p2.Play();
```

Comment: The code you posted is what I already know, but thanks that u tell me it's impossible with MediaPlayer in normal way. I guess I will just create the file in temp folder locally.